# 12bit ADC as input for CORDIC

Tags: vhdl, signal-processing, fixed-point, vivado, cordic

I am new in DSP and this is problem for me.
I need convert 12bit output from ADC to 2QN number format. It is input for CORDIC IP in Vivado. Output from CORDIC are two signals in 1QN format. Sin and Cos. Quadrature signal (I and Q) I need from CORDIC to filter. Any solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem. I try shift 2 bits left and it now works. Now translate ADC output to CORDIC :-).